# Functional pattern for double fold

Tags: design-patterns, scala, functional-programming

Let the toy-class `Counter` such as:

```
class Counter private( val next: Int, val str2int: Map[String,Int] ) {
  def apply( str: String ): (Int,Counter)  = str2int get str match {
    case Some(i) => ( i, this )
    case None => ( next, new Counter( next+1, str2int + (str -> next) ) )
  }
}
object Counter {
  def apply() = new Counter( 0, Map() )
}
```

This class provides a mapping between a String and a natural number, the mapping is extended lazily each time a new String is queried.

I can then write a method which can convert a Seq of Strings in a Seq of Ints, updating the mapping during traversal. The first implementation I got is with `foldLeft`:

```
def toInt( strs: Seq[String], counter: Counter ): ( Seq[Int], Counter ) =
  strs.foldLeft( (Seq[Int](), counter) ) { (result, str) =>
    val (i, nextCounter) = result._2( str )
    ( result._1 :+ i, nextCounter )
  }
```

This works as intended:

```
val ss = Seq( "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "baz" )
val is = toInt( ss, Counter() )._1
            //is == List(0, 1, 2, 0, 2)
```

But I am not very satisfied about `toInt` implementation. The problem is that I am folding on two different values. Is there a functional programming pattern to simplify the implementation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is the `State` monad:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Counter(next: Int = 0, str2int: Map[String,Int] = Map()) {
  def apply( str: String ): (Counter, Int) = (str2int get str) fold (
    (this, _),
    (new Counter(next+1, str2int + (str -> next)), next)
  )}

type CounterState[A] = State[Counter, A]

def count(s: String): CounterState[Int] = state(_(s))

def toInt(strs: Seq[String]): CounterState[Seq[Int]] =
  strs.traverse[CounterState, Int](count)
```

The type annotation there is unfortunate, and maybe it can be eliminated somehow. Anyway, here's a run of it:

```
scala> val ss = Seq( "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "baz" )
ss: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar, baz, foo, baz)

scala> val is = toInt(ss) ! Counter()
is: Seq[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 0, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Just one question, which `traverse` function is called in `toInt`definition ? Those I've seen in `Traverse.scala` seem to take 3 type parameters.

Comment: The method being called is MA.traverse.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the fold you've got look quite a bit nicer by doing more pattern matching:

```
strs.foldLeft((Seq[Int](), counter)) { case ((xs,counter), str) =>
  val (i, nextCounter) = counter(str)
  (xs :+ i, nextCounter)
}
```

And then if you have the [pipe operator](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2009/01/pipe-operator-in-scala.html) `|>` defined somewhere, and you're comfortable with the `/:` alias for `foldLeft`, you can make that

```
((Seq[Int](), counter) /: strs) { case ((xs,counter), str) =>
  counter(str) |> { case (i,nextCounter) => (xs +: i, nextCounter) }
}
```

which is, once you're familiar with the syntax, compact and readable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the state monad is what you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps. Can you make a short illustration using my code example ?

Comment: Here a ST Monad example which could be applied to your use case: http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html

Comment: @AndreasScheinert Thanks. I'll try to read if I manage to print it (stupid firefox bug).

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad. Your state can be defined as: `type Counter[T] = State[(Int, Map[String, Int]), T]`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with folding on two values. It can be slightly improved:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def toInt( strs: Seq[String], counter: Counter ): ( Seq[Int], Counter ) =
  strs.foldLeft( (Seq[Int](), counter) ) { case ((xs, counter), str) =>
    counter(str).mapElements(xs :+ _, identity)
  }
```

Or, if you prefer,

```
def toInt( strs: Seq[String], counter: Counter ): ( Seq[Int], Counter ) =
  strs.foldLeft( (Seq[Int](), counter) ) { case ((xs, counter), str) =>
    (xs :+ (_: Int)) <-: counter(str)
  }
```

Or even,

```
def toInt( strs: Seq[String], counter: Counter ): ( Seq[Int], Counter ) =
  strs.foldLeft( (Seq[Int](), counter) ) { case (result, str) =>
    result.fold((xs, counter) =>
      counter(str).mapElements(xs :+ _, identity))
  }
```